# Matlab - Plot values from vectores with mutiple conditions

Tags: matlab, if-statement, vector, conditional-statements

I have my values here:

```
x=[0.125  0.250  0.375  0.500  0.625  0.750  0.875 1.000  1.125  1.250  ...]  
y=[4.1  4.6  4.3  4.4  4.8  4.6  4.3  4.9 4.1  4.2 ...]
```

Then I want all the values `>4.5` **but**:

- If I have an isolated value it should be discarded;
- If I have an isolated value but it is surrounded by two values `>4.5`, then it should count.

So the result should be:

```
xx=[0.625  0.750  0.875 1.000  ...]
yy=[4.8  4.6  4.3  4.9  ...]

plot(x,y,'g',xx,yy,'k')
```

Comment: What would happen when your y-data were: `[4.9 3 4.6 4.1 4.7 4.1 4.2 4.6 4.3 4.9...]`? Would this result in: `[4.9 4.6 4.7 4.6 4.9...]`?

Comment: Yes that's the best way, i didn't realize that could happen!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me this is what you want:

```
x=[0.125  0.250  0.375  0.500  0.625  0.750  0.875 1.000  1.125  1.250]  
y=[4.1  4.6  4.3  4.4  4.8  4.6  4.3  4.9 4.1  4.2]  

xx = x(y > 4.5 | [0, (arrayfun(@(n) (y(n-1) > 4.5 & y(n+1) ...
   > 4.5 & y(n) <= 4.5), 2:length(y)-1)), 0])
yy = y(y > 4.5 | [0, (arrayfun(@(n) (y(n-1) > 4.5 & y(n+1) ...
   > 4.5 & y(n) <= 4.5), 2:length(y)-1)), 0])

xx =
   0.25000   0.62500   0.75000   0.87500   1.00000
yy =
   4.6000   4.8000   4.6000   4.3000   4.9000
```

**Update:** With new sample data from comments:

```
y = [4.9 3 4.6 4.1 4.7 4.1 4.2 4.6 4.3 4.9];

yy =
    4.9000    3.0000    4.6000    4.1000    4.7000    4.6000    4.3000    4.9000
```

It *could* also be that you want:

```
xx = x((y > 4.5 & [1, (arrayfun(@(n) (y(n-1) > 4.5 | y(n+1) ...
     > 4.5), 2:length(y)-1)), 1])  | [0, (arrayfun(@(n) (y(n-1) > 4.5 & y(n+1) ...
     > 4.5 & y(n) <= 4.5), 2:length(y)-1)), 0])
yy = y((y > 4.5 & [1, (arrayfun(@(n) (y(n-1) > 4.5 | y(n+1) ...
     > 4.5), 2:length(y)-1)), 1])  | [0, (arrayfun(@(n) (y(n-1) > 4.5 & y(n+1) ...
     > 4.5 & y(n) <= 4.5), 2:length(y)-1)), 0])

xx =
   0.62500   0.75000   0.87500
yy =
   4.8000   4.6000   4.3000
```

Comment: ... except that "If I have an isolated value but it is between two values >4.5, then it should be counted"

Comment: except that if the value>4.5 is isolated it shouldn't be counted :D

Comment: @TheMinion, I'm not sure that's correct. 4.9 is included. It looks as though it's just poorly phrased..? Hmm, but the first 4.6 is not. A comment from OP would be nice here... OP?

Comment: I think he thought about looping through the data and if he an element was bigger `4.5` he wants to check rather the next or the one after the next one (whats the word in english?) is also bigger `4.5`. So the first `4.6` is not included while the `4.9`is included because two elements prior to it was also `>4.5`.

Comment: Has you said is exactly this [4.9 3 4.6 4.1 4.7 4.1 4.2 4.6 4.3 4.9...] the result would be [4.9 4.6 4.7 4.6 4.9...]

Comment: Sorry this is a problem about the level of the sea, and i think, that sometimes, the data can have some type of error, or something, I would consider: 

[4.9 3 4.6 4.1 4.7 4.1 4.2 4.6 4.3 4.9...]
result
[4.9 3 4.6 4.1 4.7 4.6 4.3 4.9...]

Comment: @user3683409: In that case, my first answer fits! (I think)

Comment: If the posted solution (from @user3683409) is right than yours is obvious wrong. You would have to add another case into your conditions. My Solution returns the same result as posted by @user3683409. And for some unknown reasons its even faster, at least when i used `y=4+rand(1,1000000);`to generate data between 4 and 5 yours takes a few seconds while my solution takes less than 1. I wasn't able to check the results, since the case which i take into account ain't been taken into account in your code Robert.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with for-loop since the original question was tagged with `for-loop`. Which returns exactly the solution for the example:

```
v=[0,0,y,0,0];
u=[0,0,x,0,0];
for k=3:1:numel(v)
    if v(k)>4.5 && (v(k-2)>4.5 || v(k-1)>4.5 || v(k+1)>4.5 || v(k+2)>4.5) 
    elseif v(k)<4.5 && v(k-1)>4.5 && v(k+1)>4.5 
    else
        v(k)=0;
    end
end
yy=v(v>0);
xx=u(v>0);
figure(2)
plot(x,y,'g',xx,yy,'k')
```

This code can be optimizated by changing the if cases. I used this set up because it is exactly as the question was asked.